# Python Pandas dataframe: Collect values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
      var_1     var_2                         item_list 
0         0         1         [beer, apple, pear, rice]    
1         0         1          [egg, banana, oil, pear]   
2         0         1                    [beer, noodle]    
3         1         0                    [tomato, milk]    
4         1         0                           [apple]
```

Is it possible to collect all items in the item_list using data-frame apply function? The output should be something like `[beer, apple, pear, rice, egg, banana, oil, pear, ...]` without duplicates in the list.

Or I have to iterate cell by cell to collect all values in to one list?

Comment: What is desired output? What means collect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `Series`, [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and convert [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print df['item_list'].apply(pd.Series).stack().tolist()
['beer', 'apple', 'pear', 'rice', 'egg', 'banana', 'oil', 
 'pear', 'beer', 'noodle', 'tomato', 'milk', 'apple']
```

If you need remove duplicates use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) or `set`:

```
print df['item_list'].apply(pd.Series).stack().drop_duplicates().tolist()
['beer', 'apple', 'pear', 'rice', 'egg', 'banana', 'oil', 'noodle', 'tomato', 'milk']

print list(set(df['item_list'].apply(pd.Series).stack().tolist()))
['tomato', 'oil', 'apple', 'pear', 'milk', 'beer', 'noodle', 'rice', 'egg', 'banana']
```

EDIT:

If you need remove duplicates in each row first:

```
print df['item_list'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(set(x)))).stack().drop_duplicates().tolist()
```

Comment: No problem, give me time.

Comment: Thanks! One issue I ran into is the first step : df['item_list'].apply(pd.Series).stack().drop_duplicates().tolist() really takes a long time due to the size of the data set. E.g. 'apple' actually appears 1 million times in the first list, which makes the program hang ... I am wondering is it possible to avoid collecting all duplicates items in one list first?

Answer (score 2):

If your DataFrame is `df`, then you can use

```
import itertools

itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.item_list)
```

to create an iterable of all the items. If you do

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.item_list))
```

then it will become a list.

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'item_list': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]})

import itertools

>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.item_list.values))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: thanks. But the list doesn't seem to remove duplicates... is it possible to not collecting duplicates in a list first ... for example, I would have 1 million '1' , which makes it impossible to collect them in one list first ...

Answer (score 1):

```
> l= list(df['item_list'] 
> flattened_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
> flattened = set(flattened_list)
> pprint.pprint(flattened)
{'apple',
 'banana',
 'beer',
 'egg',
 'milk',
 'noodle',
 'oil',
 'pear',
 'rice',
 'tomato'}
```

Hope that helps.